# How to welcome a new user or welcome the recurring user using jquery cookies?

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, jquery-cookie

I'm trying to create a Welcome page for new and former users using cookies in jquery. However, when I submit the form using new data for each user it doesn't say "Welcome New User". It always welcome the user as if he's already a submit a form on the site.

```
 <h1 class="center"> 
        <span id="wel"></span>
 </h1> 
 <form id="form" autocomplete="on">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter the first name" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" maxlength="25">
    <br>Last Name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter the last name" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" maxlength="25">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Place Order!" />
 </form>

    var customername = []; // outside the function
    var fname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lname = $("#lastname").val();     
    customername = $.cookie('fullname', fname + " " + lname, {expires: 365});
    if(customername == null) {
            $("#wel").html("Welcome New Customer");
        } else {
            $("#wel").html("Welcome " + $.cookie("fullname"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the cookie will **always** get created, passing through empty values, because you are **creating** the cookie directly before checking that it exists:

```
customername = $.cookie('fullname', fname + " " + lname, {expires: 365});
if(customername == null) {}
```

In the above code, `customername` will never havea  value of `null`. To get around this, what you need to do is define the `customername` variable outside of the function, but not assign anything to it (not even a 'null'):

```
var customername;
if(customername == null) {
    $("#wel").html("Welcome New Customer");
} else {
    $("#wel").html("Welcome " + $.cookie("fullname"));
}
```

Then wrap the cookie creation inside of the form submission:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var fname = $("#firstname").val();
    var lname = $("#lastname").val();     
    customername = $.cookie('fullname', fname + " " + lname, {expires: 365});
});
```

This way, when the user visits the site, the cookie won't automatically get created; it will only get created on form submission.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Does the one with the `var customername` block of code should be outside of the function as well?

Comment: There are technically no 'functions' at all in the code. You should just need to post the code above 'as is', with the top section directly above the bottom section, making sure to wrap the combined code in `<script>` tags.

Comment: Thank you I finally got it. I appreciate the help :)